# Copying and Pasting the (renamed) keyframes of the bones of the Armature A to Armature B breaks the mesh of the character

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to add (copy and paste) a little bit of keyframes from the armature A to the armature B. The first armature is on the blender session A and the second one is on the blender session B. The keyframes that are saved on the armature A have been caught detecting the movements of my right hand with the kinect v2 and the brekel pro hands tool. Below you can see the matches between the names of the fingers used by the brekel tool and the names of the same bones used by the armature B. I have renamed the fingers of the bones of the Armature B with the names of the fingers of the bones of the Armature A.

> Armature B     = Armature A
>
> fing_thumb_1_L = LeftHandThumb1
>
> fing_thumb_2_L = LeftHandThumb2
>
> fing_thumb_3_L = LeftHandThumb3
>
> fing_ind_1_L = LeftHandIndex1
>
> fing_ind_2_L = LeftHandIndex2
>
> fing_ind_3_L = LeftHandIndex3
>
> fing_mid_1_L = LeftHandMiddle1
>
> fing_mid_2_L = LeftHandMiddle2
>
> fing_mid_3_L = LeftHandMiddle3
>
> fing_ring_1_L = LeftHandRing1
>
> fing_ring_2_L = LeftHandRing2
>
> fing_ring_3_L = LeftHandRing3
>
> fing_lit_1_L = LeftHandPinky1
>
> fing_lit_2_L = LeftHandPinky2
>
> fing_lit_3_L = LeftHandPinky3

Below you can see a picture of the Armature A :

[image: A]

Below you can see a picture of the Armature B with the fingers bones that have been renamed :

[image: B]

According to this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0wMk7x6fmQ

In Pose mode / Pose position I have copied all the keyframes of the bones of the fingers of the Armature A ; I have selected all the bones of the Armature B and I have pasted the keyframes of the finges on the timeline of the Armature B,but as soon as I have pasted them,this is what happened :

[image: a]

Do u know why ? I have also tried to rename the deform bones with the names of the bones of the fingers of the Armature B with the names of the fingers of the bones of the Armature A,like this :

> fing_thumb_1_def_L = LeftHandThumb1
>
> fing_thumb_2_def_L = LeftHandThumb2
>
> fing_thumb_3_def_L = LeftHandThumb3
>
> fing_ind_1_def_L = LeftHandIndex1
>
> fing_ind_2_def_L = LeftHandIndex2
>
> fing_ind_3_def_L = LeftHandIndex3
>
> fing_mid_1_def_L = LeftHandMiddle1
>
> fing_mid_2_def_L = LeftHandMiddle2
>
> fing_mid_3_def_L = LeftHandMiddle3
>
> fing_ring_1_def_L = LeftHandRing1
>
> fing_ring_2_def_L = LeftHandRing2
>
> fing_ring_3_def_L = LeftHandRing3
>
> fing_lit_1_def_L = LeftHandPinky1
>
> fing_lit_2_def_L = LeftHandPinky2
>
> fing_lit_3_def_L = LeftHandPinky3

but still does not work. can u explain why ? thanks.